# WooCommerce - Move product documents from product info to tabs container

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

Need some help moving my product documents from the product summary section to the WooCommerce tabs container in the product footer.

See this page: http://www.medic24.no/shop/laboratoriemedisin/avleser-senkning-microsed/

Comment: Moving from short description to description will do it right?

Comment: hmm i am not sure:O?

Comment: This code movs it but to the buttom of the product page. How do i place it inside a tab? besides my description tab.:  remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( wc_product_documents(), 'render_product_documents' ), 25 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product', array( wc_product_documents(), 'render_product_documents' ), 10 );

Answer (score 0):

**1.First you have to add new product tab:**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );
function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {
// Adds the new tab
  $tabs['desc_tab'] = array(
    'title'     => __( 'Additional Information', 'woocommerce' ),
    'priority'  => 50,
    'callback'  => 'woo_new_product_tab_content'
  );
};
```

**2. Add Content to Custom Tab**

```
function woo_new_product_tab_content()  {
  // The new tab content
  $prod_id = get_the_ID();
  echo get_post_meta($prod_id,'additional information',true) ;
}
```

you can try using the above.